# How to create horizontal image scrolling in xamarin cross platform?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Below is an image that I want to achieve using Xamarin cross-platform but I don't know how to do that. As like in play store we can horizontally scroll the apps. So please tell me how to do that.

[image: It is showing the image sliders]

Comment: Look up ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Out of box Xamarin doesn't have any control that has `DataTemplate` and horizontal scrolling. Unfortunately I am not aware of any plugin either (at least not true DataTemplate that would allow unlimited number of items without performance and even stability problems). If you are fine with limited number of items you may want to use `StackPanel` and insert items in it. Otherwise you need to use the native control for each platform that provides this.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing using [Sharpnado.Forms.HorizontalListView](https://www.sharpnado.com/a-real-horizontal-list-view/) component. You can achieve the horizontal image scrolling collection.

One more component you can use is [XamarinHorizontalList](https://github.com/DanielCauser/XamarinHorizontalList).

Comment: I am getting the collection from Api. Does it able to handle large data.

Comment: I don't see any issue in this component. Try implementing, make sure your image size is smaller hence loading time will be reduced.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21410687)

Comment: @LordWilmore I have designed the similar UI using these components. You can edit my answer if you find something more for this problem.

Comment: Please update your answer to include an example of usage rather than just referring to some control

Comment: Onclick of the image the video should play.How to achieve this in Xamarin.

Comment: @ShilpaKopparad you can add gesture to the image placed inside the <DataTemplate> of <HorizontalListView.ItemTemplate>